# Performing a Python scripted tool based on whether a field is populated or not

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, dissolve

My question is if I'm running the ArcMap Dissolve tool through a Python script, how can I tell it to check for attributes in one field, and if that field is empty, to perform the tool on another field.

To be more specific, I would like the Dissolve tool to check for route numbers in a field called [rt_shrt_nm] (which are provided when the route name is a numerical value).  But if that field is empty (which is sometimes is if the field has textual route names) to perform the tool on the [rt_long_nm] field instead.

This is what I'm working with now, just to give you a better idea, even though I know its probably wildly wrong:

```
if [rt_shrt_nm] is null:
        arcpy.Dissolve_management(OutShapesFCname, outGDB, ["rt_long_nm"], "", "", "")
elif:
        arcpy.Dissolve_management(OutShapesFCname, outGDB, ["rt_shrt_nm"], "", "", "")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a [search cursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/SearchCursor/018w00000011000000/) to find out if there are any rows in a table with empty string (i.e., "").

```
fc = r"C:\ArcGIS\Default.gdb\Parcels"

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,"RouteName") as scur:
    for field in scur:
        if field[0] == "":
            #dissolve on one field
        else:
            #dissolve on another field
```

Answer (score 1):

I would generate a list from the `rt_long_nm` field with a list comprehension and use that for the logic check.  The list comprehension searches for all values except for `None` and adds those to a list.  If the length of the list equals 0, perform some action, else perform another action.

```
import arcpy

OutShapesFCname = r'C:\path\to\fc'

vals = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(OutShapesFCname, ["rt_long_nm"]) if row[0] is not None]

if len(vals) == 0:
        arcpy.Dissolve_management(OutShapesFCname, outGDB, ["rt_long_nm"], "", "", "")
else:
        arcpy.Dissolve_management(OutShapesFCname, outGDB, ["rt_shrt_nm"], "", "", "")
```